# Actual documentation for STL

Tags: stl, documentation, c++11

Where can I find relevant documentation for the STL for compilers which support c++0x?

I am interested primarily to find documentation on Parallel algorithms and multithreading.

Comment: Sorry to be obsessively pedantic, but the correct name is the "C++ Standard Library". The "STL" is archaic and nonstandard.  (But, yeah, we all know what you mean.)

Comment: Before asking for documentation, you may wish to indicate which compiler you are using.  Normally portability makes this an inappropriate question to ask.  However, C++0x is not finalized and support for its prospective features varies somewhat between compilers.

Comment: See [GCC C++0x Status Page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for a list of supported features.  Based purely on the chart at that url, I recommend GCC 4.4 or higher if you want to play with C++0x.  If the documentation you eventually find is not GCC-specific, you will want to consult these documents while reading the material to verify which features are available.  Pay special attention to the concurrency section of that table, which is mostly unimplemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++0x November 2010 N3225 draft can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf). It contains details on the standard library.

That's the definitive reference. Wikipedia also has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) which gives a brief overview of some of the new stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that I need. I would like something like cplusplus.com.

Comment: @niXman: It is what you need because it's the only source with authority.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx) has some of it.  I don't like their format, but it may be what you're looking for.